# Adjusting height after setting width 100% in css

Tags: css

In Bootstrap 4, I created a div named circle inside col-md-2. this is the width of this I made 100%. I want the shape to be square when it is four. In this case, when I give the height 100%, it extends to the bottom of the page. but I want it to be four times equal. what can I do?

```
.circle{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: tomato;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS both margin and padding are relative to width, not height. You can use it to make a square by setting for example `padding-bottom: 100%`, which will pad the bottom by 100% of width.

Example would be

CSS

```
.square {
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="square"></div>
```

If you want to put elements **inside that square** you can add another element with `position: absolute` inside it that can contain your elements.

Example would be

CSS

```
.square {
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.square-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="square">
  <div class="square-content">your stuff goes here</div>
</div>
```